# Counting split rules in decision trees in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to count each unique split rule from a data frame of decision trees in R. For example, if I have a data frame containing 4 trees like the one shown below:

```
df <- data.frame(
  var = c('x10', NA, NA, 
          'x10', NA, 'x7', NA, NA,
          'x5', 'x2', NA, NA, 'x9', NA, NA,
          'x5', NA, NA),
  num = c(1,1,1,
          2,2,2,2,2,
          1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
          2,2,2),
  iter = c(rep(1, 8), rep(2, 10))
)

> df
    var num iter
1   x10   1    1
2  <NA>   1    1
3  <NA>   1    1
4   x10   2    1
5  <NA>   2    1
6    x7   2    1
7  <NA>   2    1
8  <NA>   2    1
9    x5   1    2
10   x2   1    2
11 <NA>   1    2
12 <NA>   1    2
13   x9   1    2
14 <NA>   1    2
15 <NA>   1    2
16   x5   2    2
17 <NA>   2    2
18 <NA>   2    2
```

The `var` column contains the variable name used in the splitting rule and is ordered by *depth first*. So, for example, the 4 trees created from that data would look like this:

[image: decision trees]

I'm trying to find a way to return the count of each pair of variables used in a split rule, but grouped by `iter`. For example, if we look at the 2nd tree (i.e.,`num == 2`, `iter == 1`) we can see that `x7` splits on `x10`. so, the pair `x10:x7` appears 1 time when `iter == 1`.

My desired output would look something like this:

```
 allSplits count iter
1    x10:x7     1    1
2     x5:x2     1    2
3     x5:x9     1    2
```

Any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a package that knows how to operate on this kind of data frame, but maybe these two hand-crafted recursive functions can get you started.

```r
mkTree <- function(x, pos = 1L) {
    var <- x[pos]
    if (is.na(var)) {
        list(NA_character_, NULL, NULL, 1L)
    } else {
        node <- vector("list", 4L)
        node[[1L]] <- var
        node[[2L]] <- l <- Recall(x, pos + 1L)
        node[[3L]] <- r <- Recall(x, pos + 1L + l[[4L]])
        node[[4L]] <- 1L + l[[4L]] + r[[4L]]
        node
    }
}
```

```r
tabTree <- function(tree, sep = ":") {
    x <- rep.int(NA_character_, tree[[4L]])
    pos <- 1L
    recurse <- function(subtree) {
        var1 <- subtree[[1L]]
        if (!is.na(var1)) {
            for (i in 2:3) {
                var2 <- subtree[[c(i, 1L)]]
                if (!is.na(var2)) {
                    x[pos] <<- paste0(var1, sep, var2)
                    pos <<- pos + 1L
                    Recall(subtree[[i]])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    recurse(tree)
    x <- x[!is.na(x)]
    if (length(x)) {
        x <- factor(x)
        setNames(tabulate(x), levels(x))
    } else {
        integer(0L)
    }
}
```

`mkTree` transforms into recursive lists the segments of `var` in your data frame that specify a tree. Nodes in these recursive structures have the form:

```r
list(variable_name, left_node, right_node, subtree_size)
```

`tabTree` takes the `mkTree` result and returns a named integer vector tabulating the splits. So you could do

```r
f <- function(x) tabTree(mkTree(x))
L <- tapply(df[["var"]], df[c("num", "iter")], f, simplify = FALSE)
```

to get a list matrix storing the tabulated splits for each `[num, iter]` pair (i.e., for each tree).

```r
L
##    iter
## num 1         2        
##   1 integer,0 integer,2
##   2 1         integer,0

L[2L, 1L]
## [[1]]
## x10:x7 
##      1 

L[1L, 2L]
## [[1]]
## x5:x2 x5:x9 
##     1     1
```

And you could sum over `num` to get tabulated splits for each level of `iter`.

```r
g <- function(l) {
    x <- unlist(unname(l))
    tapply(x, names(x), sum)
}
apply(L, 2L, g)
## $`1`
## x10:x7 
##      1 

## $`2`
## x5:x2 x5:x9 
##     1     1
```